# Try...catch block doesn't define variable

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a program, which takes a parameter from the `args[]` array, defined in the main method, but has a backup in case that isn't defined, in the form of a try...catch block, which, if an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception is thrown, instead uses a method called `getInt` to prompt the user to enter a variable. But, for some reason, when I try to use that variable, my compiler says that it cannot find it. I have the following code:

```
try {
    int limit = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    int limit = getInt("Limit? ");
}
int[] p = getPrimes(limit);
```

`getPrimes` is another method I have, which returns an array of prime numbers starting from 2 and up to a specified number (using the Sieve of Atkin). Anyway, when I write `int[] p = getPrimes(limit);` and try compiling, it says that the "limit" variable is not defined. Help please!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should declare it outside the block:

```
int limit;
try {
    limit = Integer.parseInt(stuff[0]);
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    limit = getInt("Limit? ");
}
int[] p = getPrimes(limit);
```

Answer (score 2):

declare `limit` outside of catch block, currently it is under the scope of catch block `catch{}`

Answer (score 2):

```
int limit;
try {
    limit = Integer.parseInt(stuff[0]);
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    limit = getInt("Limit? ");
}
int[] p = getPrimes(limit);
```

In your program you have created 2 local Limit variable one in `try` block and another in `catch` block.

Declare it outside the try block

Answer (score 1):

Define limit variable outside of try/catch block, you do not have access to variables defined inside try block outside. You would also have to initialize it if you are calling it outside of try block as in your case here.